# Passing select input array from a view to a controller (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, select

as the title says I am currently trying to pass an array of values from a `<select>` from a view to a controller to be batch inserted 
Here is the part segment from the view class:

```
       foreach($results as $row){echo '<tr>';       
    echo '<td> <select name="Select[]" value="'.$count.'" >
            <option value="Select">Select</option>}
             <option value="P">P</option>
             <option value="F">F</option>
            </select></td>';
    echo '<td> <select name="Select2[]" value="'.$count2.'" >
            <option value="Select">Select</option>}
             <option value="A">A</option>
             <option value="B">B</option>
             <option value="C">C</option>
             <option value="D">D</option>
             <option value="F">F</option>
            </select></td>';


    $count++;
    $count2++;
}
```

Here is the segment of code from the controller class:

```
$something = $this->input->post('select');
$something2 = $this->input->post('select2');
$classID = $this->input->post('classID');
$studentID = $this->input->post('studentID');
$count = 0;
$insertCount = 0;
$newEntries = array ();
$newRow = array (
    "employeeID" == $myID[0]->employeeID,
    "studentID" == $studentID[$count]->studentID,
    "type" == 'Midterm',
    "grade" == $something[$index[$count]],
    "classID" == $classID[$index[$count]]
);
die(print_r($newRow));
$newRow2 = array (
    "employeeID" == $myID[0]->employeeID,
    "studentID" == $classID[$index[$count]],
    "type" == 'Final',
    "grade" == $something2[$index[$count]],
    "classID" == $classID[$index[$count]]
);
$newEntries[$index[$insertCount]] == $newRow;
            $insertCount++;
$newEntries[$index[$insertCount]] == $newRow2;
$insertCount++;
$count++;
    }
```

So the problem is that for the class and student ID's it is passing only the last results of the results back to the controller. I can live with this error for now but whats really important is that when this is run $something only contains the value "1" which is determined by a `die(print_r($something));`

Comment: I think you should initialize $count=0 at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

To get proper result use flag TRUE

```
die(print_r($newRow, true));
```

print_r will return value rather print it to output